# Toggle Two Divs, with just Javascript. No jquery

Tags: javascript

Thanks in advance for your help! My JavaScript skills are pretty limited.

I'm working with a wordpress site, trying to toggle between two divs.

I've searched for hours and can't seems to find a solution, also, I can't use jquery.

Here is what I have, thank you!

```html
<div class="one">Content One</div>
<div class="two">Content Two</div>
<button>Previous</button>
<button>Next</button>
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to toggle the divs, try this

```js
function toggle(){
  let one = document.getElementById("one");
  let two = document.getElementById("two");
  one.classList.toggle("hidden");
  two.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="one">Content One</div>
<div id="two" class="two hidden">Content Two</div>
<button onclick="toggle();">Previous</button>
<button onclick="toggle();">Next</button>
```